# guardar archivo en r fomato xslx con password

Tags: r

Estoy usando la siguiente función:

```
write.xlsx (df,"archivoexistente.xlsx", sheetname = "nuevoarchivo", password = "123lsk")
```

El código funciona normal sin embargo se tarda demasiado guardando el archivo, mi pregunta es si es normal que se tarde tanto, a veces 10 minutos en un archivo de 156408 bytes y si hay alguna forma de que se tarde menos, en vista que me esta ocasionando retrasos en el proceso a diferencia que cuando se guarda en formato cvs ya que este si es casi que inmediato.

Comment: Hola Ivan, existen dos funciones  `write.xlsx` en r. Una en el paquete `xlsx` y otra en el paquete `openxlsx`. ¿Cual usas tu? En mi caso me gusta más el paquete `openxlsx`, en este paquete guarde un excel rápidamente. También probe `xlsx`, y este tarde mucho tiempo corriendo hasta que al final me lanzo un error.

Comment: Roger buenas noches, utilizo ambos pero para poder guardar con password no me funciona openxlsx por esto utilizo wtrite.xlsx